# (window).load(function() { ... }); making the whole page go white

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function that resizes a div on the basis of whether or not its scrollHeight is greater than 175. It worked fine like this:

```
var this_div = $('#content_' + <?php echo $counter ?>);
var this_div_height = this_div[0].scrollHeight; // 0 refers to the 0th child, i. e. the div itself
if (this_div_height > 175) {
    document.write('<a id="slide_arrow_<?php echo $counter ?>" class="clear_both slide_arrow" href=\'javascript:toggle("<?php echo $counter; ?>", "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>")\'></a>');
}
```

The problem was that some generated items which contributed to the div height were not being taken into consideration, not having yet been loaded when the script is run, so I put it inside of a (window).load(function() { ...}); like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var this_div = $('#content_' + <?php echo $counter ?>);
    var this_div_height = this_div[0].scrollHeight; // 0 refers to the 0th child, i. e. the div itself
    if (this_div_height > 175) {
        document.write('<a id="slide_arrow_<?php echo $counter ?>" class="clear_both slide_arrow" href=\'javascript:toggle("<?php echo $counter; ?>", "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>")\'></a>');
    }
});
```

...and now what happens is that the content blinks on the page for like a nanosecond and then the whole window is just white.

Comment: don't use `document.write`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is caused by your use of `document.write()`. After the page has fully loaded and the whole document has been parsed, subsequent calls to `document.write()` **obliterate** whatever was there.

You're using jQuery, so you can just use `.append()` to add the new content.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document.write() which replaces everything on the page, append to the body:

```
var newsutff = $('<a id="slide_arrow_<?php echo $counter ?>" class="clear_both slide_arrow" href=\'javascript:toggle("<?php echo $counter; ?>", "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>")\'></a>');
$('body').append(newstuff);
```